# Why GLM_CONSTEXPR_SIMD?

Tags: performance, c++11, simd, constexpr, glm-math

The [OpenGL mathematics library](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html) defines a macro `GLM_CONSTEXPR_SIMD` which causes expressions like `vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` to be a `constexpr` *only* when generating platform-independent code, i.e., only when`GLM_ARCH` is `GLM_ARCH_PURE`.

I assume this is done for performance reasons, but why would making something non-`constexpr` increase performance?  And how does SIMD play a role in the decision?

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably related to the fact that SIMD intrinsics are not defined constexpr. When you generate platform-independent code, it does not use intrinsics and thus, it can be declared constexpr. However, as soon as you pinpoint a platform e.g. with SSE/AVX, in order to benefit from these SIMD functions, constexpr must be stripped away.

Additional info available at [Constexpr and SSE intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880079/constexpr-and-sse-intrinsics)